# Redirect StandardOutput from a process

Tags: winforms, process, ffmpeg, c++-cli

I am working on C++/CLI winforms
how to redirect standard output to textbox?
I followed this video, but it didn't work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDTCviA-5M8

I can see output in console window, but till process finishes GUI freezes!

```
ProcessStartInfo ^psi = gcnew ProcessStartInfo("D://ffmpeg.exe", "-y -i D://1.avi D://process.mp4");        
psi->WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
psi->UseShellExecute = false;
psi->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process->StartInfo = psi;

process->Start();
String^ details = process->StandardOutput->ReadToEnd();
textBox1->Text = details; 
Console::WriteLine(details);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is your reading of the standard output. As you have only one threadf involved in your code, there is no other option then to let everything happen in succession. If you want to see the progress/output of a long running command tool you'll need to use the [OutputDataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event from the Process instance.

The following code uses that technique to reach your goal:

```
ref class ProcessForm:Form
{
    TextBox ^textBox1 = gcnew TextBox();
    Button ^button = gcnew Button();

public:
    ProcessForm() {
        this->Width = 325;
        this->Height = 450;
        textBox1->Top = 20;
        textBox1->Width = 300;
        textBox1->Height = 400;
        textBox1->Multiline = true;

        button->Text = "Start";
        button->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &ProcessForm::OnClick);

        this->Controls->Add(textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(button);
    }

    void ProcessForm::OnClick(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e)
    {
        Process ^process = gcnew Process();
        // "D://ffmpeg.exe", "-y -i D://1.avi D://process.mp4"
        ProcessStartInfo ^psi = gcnew ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c dir \\*.exe /s");
        psi->WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
        psi->UseShellExecute = false;
        psi->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process->StartInfo = psi;

        // handle incoming data from the standard output stream
        process->OutputDataReceived += gcnew DataReceivedEventHandler(this, &ProcessForm::OnOutputDataReceived);

        process->Start();
        // start reading from the standard ouput stream on a different thread
        process->BeginOutputReadLine();

        // prevent starting again ...
        process->Exited += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &ProcessForm::OnExited);
        this->button->Enabled = false;
    }

    delegate void UpdateHandler(System::String ^text);

    // output the stuff on screen
    void ProcessForm::Update(System::String ^text)
    {
        textBox1->Text += text;
        Console::WriteLine(text);
    }

    // is invoked on a seperate thread if the process writes 
    // to the console
    void  ProcessForm::OnOutputDataReceived(System::Object ^sender, System::Diagnostics::DataReceivedEventArgs ^e)
    {
        // handle switching to the UI thread
        if (textBox1->InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateHandler^ handler = gcnew UpdateHandler(this, &ProcessForm::Update);
            textBox1->Invoke(handler, e->Data);
        }
        else 
        {
            Update(e->Data);
        }
    }

    // if we're done enable the button again
    void ProcessForm::OnExited(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e)
    {
        this->button->Enabled = true;
    }

};
```

Notice the need to use [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) as the event method is called from a non-UI thread.